# Vue Fullpage Unknown element

Tags: vue.js

I have a issue and I tried to solved but no results.

I install vue-fullpage, and I imported this and css.

But I have the next error

```
Unknown custom element: <full-page>
```

If I check the "app.js", the Vue component full-page is loaded, but it still doesn't work

The code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <full-page :options="options" id="fulp" ref="fullpage">
      <div class="section">
        <h3>vue-fullpage.js</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <div class="slide">
          <h3>Slide 2.1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <h3>Slide 2.2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <h3>Slide 2.3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <h3>Section 3</h3>
      </div>
    </full-page>
  </div>
</template>

<script> 
 import FullPage from 'vue-fullpage.js'


  export default {
    name: 'Test full page',
    data() {
      return {
        options: {
          navigation: true,
          anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3'],
          sectionsColor: ['#41b883', '#ff5f45', '#0798ec', '#fec401', '#1bcee6', '#ee1a59', '#2c3e4f', '#ba5be9',
            '#b4b8ab'
          ]
        },
      }
    },

  }

</script>

<style>
  @import 'https://unpkg.com/fullpage.js/dist/fullpage.min.css';

</style>
```

**Update:** 
Also i tried to put the attr components:

```
export default {
        name: 'Test full page',
        components: {FullPage},
        data() {
          return {
            options: {
              navigation: true,
              anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3'],
              sectionsColor: ['#41b883', '#ff5f45', '#0798ec', '#fec401', '#1bcee6', '#ee1a59', '#2c3e4f', '#ba5be9',
                '#b4b8ab'
              ]
            },
          }
        },
```

But I get other error with "Vue.component is not a function"

Comment: If I put it, I get 2 erros, first unkown element and then Vue.component is not a function

Comment: Please update your question so I don't have to guess where you _put it_

Comment: Done. I updated the post

Comment: Your code doesn't look anything like the [usage guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fullpage.js#usage). What documentation are you following?

Comment: That. I tried put it in main.js, the error, after I follow a youtube video, and same error. Don't find the component, I don't know why. I install other component to test and work perfect, just happen with it

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be using the [vue-fullpage.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fullpage.js#usage) library according to their guide.

They provide the library as a Vue plugin so you need to *use* it in your root `Vue` instance, eg

```js
// main.js or whatever
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueFullPage from 'vue-fullpage.js'

Vue.use(VueRouter) // Note: Do NOT try and pass in multiple plugins
Vue.use(VueFullPage)
```

This will install the `full-page` component globally so you don't need to import it into your component.

Comment: I tried global: .. import FullPage from 'vue-fullpage.js' Vue.use(Router, FullPage) ... but I still.

Comment: @Carloscito `Vue.use` does not take multiple plugin arguments. Use separate `Vue.use()` calls for each

Comment: And what error would that be, **exactly**? Please edit your question to include your latest code and any error messages **in detail**